# Install specific chromedriver for protractor

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue with chrome driver that runs on the CircleCi. 
The problem is that when running:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update
```

and then checking the version of chromedriver and selenium with the command:

```
ls -lt node_modules/protractor/selenium
```

it shows the latest versions are:

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
chromedriver
chromedriver_2.15.zip
```

According to the npm.taobao.org [note](http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/2.15/notes.txt) ChromeDriver version 2.15 supports Chrome v40-43. But CicleCi [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/environment) says that it uses Chrome version 38.0. 
Consequently, I need to use ChromeDriver v2.13 which is compatible with Chrome v38.0.
My question is that how can I force `webdriver-manager` to use ChromeDriver v2.13 instead of the latest one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should probably be a feature request for the protractor team. But this is what I recommend you to do:

Change the `webdriverVersions` property on protractor's [config.json](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/aded26bc9ee6172d6f64361207f6a8b04da09b0d/config.json#L2) file. webdriver-manager uses this [property](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/aded26bc9ee6172d6f64361207f6a8b04da09b0d/bin/webdriver-manager#L18) to download the files.

Comment: This was super helpful for me!  I wound up adding some postinstall scripts to my package.json that uses sed to replace the version in protractors config file after installing the package.  Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/SteveAquino/dc8b6b1cae0554193a2a

Answer (score 0):

@Andres suggested a good solution, but the easiest can be adding a `circle.yml` file that contains the following command to upgrade chrome version:

```
test:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade google-chrome-stable
```